# How to add TextView inside a GridView filled with ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview, baseadapter

I have a GridView where I add images directly with ImageView (I don't use an XML for the image). Now, I want to add image name at the bottom of each cell using a TextView. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

**Custom Adapter Class:**

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int imageWidth;
    private GridView imageCarrete;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
                            int imageWidth, GridView imageCarrete) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._filePaths = filePaths;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        this.imageCarrete = imageCarrete;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this._filePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // get screen dimensions
        Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
            imageWidth);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        // Listener del GridView
        imageCarrete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                _activity.startActivityForResult(i, 1234);
            }
        });

        return imageView;
    }

    /*
     * Resizing image size
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
        try {

            File f = new File(filePath);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void remove(String path){
        _filePaths.remove(path);
    }

}
```

**GridView XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="#000000">
</GridView>
```

Comment: it is better to create an xml file.. but if you dont want that then create a linear layout and assign him weightsum 2 with Vertical orientation. and then create image view and text view, and then add both these views in linear layout. you task will be done.

Comment: Simply embed your images inside the TextViews as **compound drawables**. And save a lot of useless Views (which is better for performances).

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Can you provide an example applied to my case? Thanks

Comment: @gilgil28 has an answer for you which is nearly perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `LinearLayout` as you are creating `Imagview` in `getView()` method...   add `ImageView` and `TextView` to it with `addView()` method.... have a look ..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LinearLayout _ll;
      if (convertView == null) {            
        _ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        _ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ImageView img  = new ImageView(mContext);
        img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));   // your image size
        img.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);                    // here pass your array list position
        _ll.addView(img);

        TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setText("dsaf");
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        _ll.addView(text);            
      } else {
          _ll = (LinearLayout) convertView;
      }
  return _ll;
}
```

You can also use `RelativeLayout` if you want to overlay your **text over image**..

Comment: yes. better to create a custom view that is actualy a `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and set custom methods to populate them easily

Comment: setBackgroundResource() accepts int as parameters, my images path are in ArrayList<String>. How can I resolve this?

Comment: you can all use `img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` if you are getting bitmap from your method

Answer (score 2):

Within your `getView()` method, replace your `ImageView` with a `TextView` with a drawable:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
 tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

you will supply the drawable to the top and `0` to the rest, ie:

```
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, yourDrawable, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How can I use a bitmap instead of drawable? Converting the bitmap to drawable doesn't work because that method only accepts int as parameters

Comment: @JohnDroid A PNG file IS a drawable. just use `R.drawable.your_image_name`

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi my images are in the sdcard and I have an ArrayList<String> which contains all image paths. I use a method that resize those images and at the end I have a bitmap. See my code above to clarify

Comment: @JohnDroid ... really horrible. Why don't you simply put the xxxhdpi versions in the xxxhdpi drawable folder and let Android do the proper scaling **down** (if you care for quality) automatically?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi because the application allows users to take pictures which are saved in the sdcard

Comment: @JohnDroid Uh... such a gear. Wasn't a simple gallery enough?